# Parsing two consecutive records in XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file:

```
<root type="service">
  <Msg Date="03/23/2013 12:00:04 AM">Request'HANDSHAKE'</Msg>
  <Msg Date="03/23/2013 12:00:04 AM">Response'RSHANDSHAKE'</Msg>
  <Msg Date="03/23/2013 12:03:04 AM">Request'HANDSHAKE'</Msg>
  <Msg Date="03/23/2013 12:03:04 AM">Response'RSHANDSHAKE'</Msg>
  <Msg Date="03/23/2013 01:34:30 PM">Request 'IQ~bbabb3ff2-...DLE~VNECTRECVBDHANDLE'</Msg>
  <Msg Date="03/23/2013 01:34:30 PM">Response SIQ~7a23da12...RDHANDLE=O000000000014'</Msg>
</root>
```

I have to parse the file and see whether every request is followed by a response. If there is no response, that indicates there was error. How can I do this in C# and preferably LINQ?

Comment: What code have you written thus far?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) for reading XML with LINQ, however I am not sure if XML guarantees order in this fashion, so LINQ to XML may not preserve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a XML parser like LINQ to XML. With that, your code could look like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
bool isError = (from e1 in doc.Root.Elements()
                where e1.Value.StartsWith("Request")
                let e2 = e1.ElementsAfterSelf().FirstOrDefault()
                where e2 == null || !e2.Value.StartsWith("Response")
                select e1).Any();
```

This literary does what you asked for: for every `Request` element, it checks that the following element exists and is a `Response` element.

If you have other requirements, e.g. `Response` element by itself is also not valid, you will have to modify the code accordingly.

Comment: this solution looks best, +1

Comment: I like this solution. It makes sense. I will try it and see whether it works for me. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Thanks svick for this sleek solution. It works like a charm. I never guessed one could do such amazing things with LINQ. Can you direct me to some good books or articles regarding LINQ. Thanks once more.

Answer (score -1):

something like this would work, I just tested it in Visual Studio, surely there are more elegant ways to do part of this using `XPATH` filters/selectors...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ParseXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String xmlString =
        @"<root type=""service"">
                <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 12:00:04 AM"">Request'HANDSHAKE'</Msg>
                <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 12:00:04 AM"">Response'RSHANDSHAKE'</Msg>
                <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 12:03:04 AM"">Request'HANDSHAKE'</Msg>
                <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 12:03:04 AM"">Response'RSHANDSHAKE'</Msg>
                <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 01:34:30 PM"">Request 'IQ~bbabb3ff2-...DLE~VNECTRECVBDHANDLE'</Msg>
                <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 01:34:30 PM"">Response SIQ~7a23da12...RDHANDLE=O000000000014'</Msg>
            </root>";

            // Create an XmlReader
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
            {
                while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Msg"))
                {
                    string request = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

                    if(reader.ReadToFollowing("Msg"))
                    {
                        string response = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

                        if (request.Contains("Request") && response.Contains("Response"))
                        {
                            // Request/Response nodes identified...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like solutions with parsing xml, however, if it adds more complexity then is has a risk to give wrong results. You will be able to identify the first mistake with this, but then request contains Response and response contains Request. If you fix that, then it is a good solution. You want to check for request not containing request, response not containing response, since question was to find the errors.

Comment: records are not containing each other in the XML fragment in the question, they are sequential and my code meets the question requirement in identifying positive cases. Shazia can start from there if believes is a good solution and complete implementation by adding error handling and special cases handling... or ognore it and use another solution with LINQ or XPATH as needed...

Comment: It works for your example, but as I meantioned in my previous comment, it should be a solution to find errors, too. If you remove one Response, then all following correct Request..Response are not detected. (because then request will be filled with the Response, and vice versa)

Answer (score -1):

Here a solution that works for valid cases and also for errors and also gives you the exact amount:

```
    String xmlString = @"<root type=""service"">
        <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 12:00:04 AM"">Request'HANDSHAKE'</Msg>
        <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 12:00:04 AM"">Response'RSHANDSHAKE'</Msg>
        <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 12:03:04 AM"">Request'HANDSHAKE'</Msg>
        <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 12:03:04 AM"">Response'RSHANDSHAKE'</Msg>
        <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 01:34:30 PM"">Request 'IQ~bbabb3ff2-...DLE~VNECTRECVBDHANDLE'</Msg>
        <Msg Date=""03/23/2013 01:34:30 PM"">Response SIQ~7a23da12...RDHANDLE=O000000000014'</Msg>
    </root>";

    String[] data = xmlString.Split(new string[] { "/Msg"},  StringSplitOptions.None);

    int errors = 0;
    Boolean secondLine = false;
    for (int i = 0; i+1 < data.Length; i ++ )
    {
        if (secondLine)
        {
            if (!data[i].Contains("Response"))
            {
                errors += 1;
            }
            secondLine = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!data[i].Contains("Request"))
            {
                errors += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                secondLine = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (secondLine) { errors += 1; }

    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Errors: " + errors.ToString());
```

Comment: You probably didn't get it the first time: **don't parse XML by hand, use a XML parser**.